# How to write over printed line in python

Tags: python, printing

I want to keep track of a functions progress (ie. how much it has processed/how much it needs to process) so I print this as part of the function and do end='\r' to reset it and write over (this way I don't print it thousands of times making it unreadable). After a few cycles, it begins to start printing over only part of what I wrote like this:

**2 / 20    223 /243    0 / 1    2.92e+02 %    Elapsed Time: 0 years 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 3 seconds    Remaining Time: 0 years 0 days                                                      minutes 0 seconds    Remaining Time: 0 years 0 days                                                     /243    0 / 1    9.63e+01 %    Elapsed Time: 0 years 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 1 seconds    Remaining Time: 0 years 0 days**

When it should look like:

**2 / 20    223 /243    0 / 1    2.92e+02 %    Elapsed Time: 0 years 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 3 seconds    Remaining Time: 0 years 0 days**

I have tried using '\x1b[2K', '\033[F','\033[A\r' (all in place of '\r') and ending my print with a long string of spaces (to hopefully clear any extra letters as the print function expands in length and contracts) and using '\r' to no avail. Does anyone have any other method? I am using python 3.0

Simplified Version of Code that Doesn't Work:

```
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss',end='\033[F')
```

Comment: Here is a simple bit of code that doesn't work with '\033[F':  for x in range(10): I added it to the original question

Comment: all depends on terminal/console which you use - not all terminals respect codes.

Comment: code `\r` is only to move cursor to the beginning of line - but this doesn't remove text - and later you have to print spaces (or new text) to remove old text. But if you always print the same text then you can't see difference

Comment: Even if I get rid of Remaining Time to limit the function down to 1 line 100% of the time, it starts printing it after the space even with end='\r'

Comment: so your terminal/console doesn't use codes.

Comment: It uses \r correctly a few times. It will work with a simple for loop then sleep function then print as long as the length doesn't vary. I just dont understand why it stops working randomly.

Comment: maybe you use different console or different IDE which doesn't use real console. And `print()` uses `sys.stdout` which may use buffer and send on screen only when it get `\n`' and sometimes code needs to use `sys.stdout.flush()` or `print(..., flush=True)` to force `stdout` to send data on screen (because you changed `end=` and now it doesn't send `\n`).